# DLL function (in C# .NET) called from pure C program causes error

Tags: c#, .net, c, visual-studio-2010, exception

I have a C program that needs some functionallity of a library that is written in C# .NET. After I googled up a way how I could do that didn't took long until I hit another problem.

It seems that calling a method/function from that library is not a problem as long as there are no compley types are returned by functions (**note:** by now this is just my guess but this is the behavior I observed so far).

I want to show you how the code looks like (**note:** this is not the actual code but it contains those parts which could be interesting):

```
// C Code calling C# function from dll

#if defined(_WIN32)
#   include <Windows.h>
#   define COBJMACROS
#   define CINTERFACE // For C-Interface
#   include <mscoree.h>
#endif

void callCSharpFunction ()
{
    HRESULT status;
    BOOL Started;
    DWORD result;
    Started = FALSE;    

    // preparation code ..

    status = ICLRRuntimeHost_ExecuteInDefaultAppDomain(
                 Host,
                 L"C:\\path\\mydll.dll",
                 L"mynamespace.myclass",
                 L"myfunction",
                 L"paramAsString",
                 &result
                 );

    // ...
}
```

The C# Code, **note** that all functions I am calling using `ICLRRuntimeHost_ExecuteInDefaultAppDomain` *must* have the same signature `int fncname(string param);`.

```
/// C#

/// @param parameter is ignored
public static int myfunction(string strParam)
{
    try {

        IComplexObject co = (IComplexObject)SingletonObject.getComplexObject();

    } catch(Exception ex) { 
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); 
        return ERR_EXCEPTION; 
    }

    if (co.IsConfigured == false) 
        co.Configure();

    if (co.IsConfigured == false) 
        return ERR_COULD_NOT_CONFIG;

    return OK;
}
```

If I call a simpler function e.g. one that has no calls itself to functions which return a complex object like `IComplexObject` everything works fine. As soon as an internal call like `(IComplexObject)SingletonObject.getComplexObject();` comes into place the program does not work correctly. An exception gets thrown saying "*Requested type was not found.*"

If you need any further information about anything let me know and I will try to give it to you.

At the end I'll show you the console output I am receiving in case someone can use that information:

```
First-chance exception at 0x758f812f in agentsib.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: EEFileLoadException at memory location 0x0012d140..
First-chance exception at 0x758f812f in agentsib.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000..
First-chance exception at 0x758f812f in agentsib.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000..
First-chance exception at 0x758f812f in agentsib.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000..
First-chance exception at 0x758f812f in agentsib.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: EEFileLoadException at memory location 0x0012d140..
First-chance exception at 0x758f812f in agentsib.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000..
First-chance exception at 0x758f812f in agentsib.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000..
First-chance exception at 0x758f812f in agentsib.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000..
First-chance exception at 0x758f812f in agentsib.exe: 0xE0434F4D: 0xe0434f4d.
First-chance exception at 0x758f812f in agentsib.exe: 0xE0434F4D: 0xe0434f4d.
'agentsib.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\sspicli.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'agentsib.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dhcpcsvc.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'agentsib.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dhcpcsvc6.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x550) has exited with code 2 (0x2).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0xf30) has exited with code -1073741510 (0xc000013a).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x910) has exited with code -1073741510 (0xc000013a).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1dd8) has exited with code -1073741510 (0xc000013a).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1b64) has exited with code -1073741510 (0xc000013a).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1dfc) has exited with code -1073741510 (0xc000013a).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x128c) has exited with code -1073741510 (0xc000013a).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0xa0c) has exited with code -1073741510 (0xc000013a).
The program '[5068] agentsib.exe: Native' has exited with code -1073741510 (0xc000013a).
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: We cannot see `ICLRRuntimeHost_ExecuteInDefaultAppDomain`. Why aren't you using UnmanagedExports, or a mixed mode C++/CLI DLL?

Comment: Looks like you need to point your internal run-time to the required assemblies for `IComplexObject`.  Also, full exception with stack trace would help.  (program debug output not so useful)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan `ICLRRuntimeHost_ExecuteInDefaultAppDomain` is the C function that calls the DLL function. Would UnmanagedExports solve this issue? The one program is written in pure C and the library I'am talking about is in C# how could mixed mode C++/CLI help me? @ebyrob I will add the full stack trace in about an hour. Need be on another machine to get it.

Comment: C++/CLI can consume C# assemblies. It's the officially supported way to do what UnmanagedExports does. UnmanagedExports would make your life really easy. You would not have to mess around getting the .net libraries loaded and initialized. Would all happen by magic.

Comment: @StefanFalk I think DavidHeffernan is implying *you* wrote ICLRRuntimeHost_ExecuteInDefaultAppDomain since it's not part of the standard API.  (I see a C++ function very similar, but not the one you mention)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan are we talking here about rewriting the library or is that just a way how to export C# libraries? (sorry if that is a stupid question but like I said I am more or less just a user of that lib - though I have access to the sourcecode). @ebyrob mscoree.h offers a C interface by simply defining the macro `#define CINTERFACE` that is why there is a 6th parameter `Host` which is something like a `this` pointer.

Comment: Pardon, hearing "pure C" to describe calling a C++ class wrapped in a C macro (in Visual C++) may have confused me.  C++/CLI would require your "pure C (Visual C++)" to become .NET.  UnmanagedExports is a way to package your C# (or C++/CLI) assemblies for use in native land.  see: http://www.mql5.com/en/articles/249

Comment: Type UnmanagedExports into websearch and find out

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion: instead of figuring out what is the problem, you can:

1. Write a mix C++/CLI DLL, it calls the C# code, and exported the functionality as DLL exported functions.
2. The C program calls the exported functions in the mixed DLL.

As how to do this, please check [This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10020/Using-managed-code-in-an-unmanaged-application).

Try to host the CLR in C program, it is possible, but complex, and hard to debug. Also, you need handle the data conversion from native to managed world, and vice verse.

Another way is: wrap the C# DLL as COM, then C DLL will use the C# DLL via COM. You don't need to create an additional DLL, but there're other drawbacks: each exported C# type has to have a GUID; data conversion goes through COM type, for plain types, they're fine; for arrays, you need to use SAFEARRY. For details: please check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645738%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: This is what David Heffernan suggested, right? This would imply a mix C++/CLI wrapper DLL. I'd like to know if there is no other way around this since the library we are talking here about is quiet large and a wrapper might add a lot of maintenance that would needed to be done.

Comment: Not sure how far you'll get with #2 (even if the DLL is C++/CLI) without some extra work towards UnmanagedExports (requires an extra compile step)

Comment: So this C++/CLI thing is not that what would make me happy?

Comment: @ebyrob I don't think C++CLI requires UnmanagedExports. It just use dllexport to export a function or class.

Comment: @Matt I stand corrected looks like **IJW** will do it given your debugging caveat.  (Trace and console still work fine though)  COM seems to never be a good idea unless you have to have it for some reason.  I think somewhere betweeen .NET 2.0 and .NET 4.0 the "extra compilation steps" must have become automatic.

Comment: @ebyrob, yes, don't use COM unless you have to.